# Taking screenshot with java

Tags: java, macos, selenium, screenshot

I am testing a game inside a web page , the code i am using is

```
 private void takeScreenShot(String screenShotName) {
        File path = new File("/Users/myUser");
        String extension = ".jpg";
        File screenShot = new File(path+"/"+screenShotName );
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, screenShot);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and the screenshot comes out like this(i have been using the same code for many applications with no problems), i am using this code on OS X.

[image: Wrong Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You may try this out:

```
   private void takeScreenShot(String screenShotName) throws AWTException, IOException {

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        String path = "\\Users\\myUser";
        String extension  = "jpg";
        String fileName = path +"\\"+ screenShotName +"."+ extension;

        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, extension , new File(fileName));           

}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly but do you have any clue why this problem occurs?